# Upload / Naming folders to a destination folder on Google Drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: html, forms, upload, google-drive-api

My skills in coding/scripting are limited, please bear with me on incorrect terminologies; I need people to input three values on the form, [Objectives, Goals, and Remarks] followed by uploading an attachment (s) to my Google Drive. The script that I found (attached below) is working but needs to be adjusted (edited) for my needs. Please, I need help with the following:

1. Right now, the files when uploaded, proceed to the default Google Drive folder. But I need them to be directed to a folder that I named, UPLOADS on my Google Drive.
2. Each uploaded file to create the same folder name at the destination, e.g., a .pdf FILE with the name "Fountain" when uploaded, to create a FOLDER with the name "Fountain" in the destination folder.

3.The upload progress bar is working fine, but I would prefer the page to refresh after each submission, so the information on the form disappears.

*The input values on the form [Objectives, Goals, and Remarks] are not being recorded anywhere, after each submission - they are not on Google sheet; Any suggestions to solve this are welcome.

Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">

    <label for="myForm">2020 Vision:</label>

    <br><br>


    <form id="myForm"> 
      <label for="myForm">Information:</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="objectives" placeholder=“Objectives:”>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="goals" placeholder=“Goals:”>
      </div>
      <div>

      <label for="fileText">Remarks:</label>

          <TEXTAREA name="projectDescription" 
          placeholder="Describe your attachment(s) here:"
          style ="width:400px; height:200px;"
          ></TEXTAREA>


      </div> 
      <br>


      <label for="attachType">Choose Attachment Type:</label>
      <br>
      <select name="attachType">
        <option value="Pictures Only">Picture(s)</option>
        <option value="Proposals Only">Documents</option>
        <option value="Pictures & Proposals">All</option>
      </select>
      <br>

      <label for="myFile">Upload Attachment(s):</label>
      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">


    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;
folderName;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    folderName = "Batch: "+new Date();
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = ‘UPLOADS’; // my desired destination folder
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, folderName);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      //uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
          width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName, folderName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    var dropbox = folderName || "UPLOADS"; //my desired destination for uploads
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand about `Can I get the script to create a folder name from the same name input on the form?`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear there. When I deploy the script as a web app, the data that is entered on the HTML form is not appearing anywhere (even on the google sheet?) So I assumed the script can rename the files as they are uploaded in the destination folder, based on the values from the input fields of the form. Thank you for the response...

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. I appreciate your assistance. Maybe I can go step by step? I would like the uploaded files to go to one folder, named "UPLOADS" on script. Right now everything I upload is going into the main Google Drive folder instead of the "Uploads" folder I created. May you kindly, help with that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, is [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bgoogle-apps-script%5d%20file%20upload%20html) useful for your situation?

Comment: Yes, the "Information" input fields are useful. They must be recorded somewhere, maybe on Google Sheet, when every person uploads a file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the method for putting values to Spreadsheet, I think that [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+setValues) will be useful. Unfortunately, I cannot still clearly see the vision of your goal from your question and replying comments. By this, I cannot propose the concrete solution. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, for your time and all the help. I will look at ([google-apps-script] [google-sheets] setValues), I hope something will work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The link of the information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+setValues). By the way, can you update your question by including the detail information about your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand about your goal.

Comment: Ok, I will update the question. Thank you. After I'm done, I will comment here, so you can review it. Sorry, I'm slow because I'm not experienced.

Comment: Tanaike, I just updated the question, I hope its a little clearer. I'm still studying the link you provided and hope to get a solution soon in linking my form to google sheet. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some little changes to your code:

### HTML file

in your "sendFileToDrive" I passed the folder name (in this case "Uploads") to your "uploadFileToDrive" in your Apps Script.

```
function sendFileToDrive(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        // set the file's name where you want to set your files 
        var folderName = "UPLOADS"; // my desired destination folder
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, folderName);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

To reset the values in your form after submitting it you can do it in the following way (Keep in mind this is vanilla JS, so there are several ways on the Internet to achieve this).

Write this line of code `document.getElementById("myForm").reset();` in your "updateProgressbar"

```
function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      //uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
      // Reset the form's fields values
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

   };
}
```

### Apps Script file

In your Apps Script code, I made these changes to create the folder from the file you just uploaded and then putting it in your "Uploads" folder. The problem you were having is you were trying to create a new folder in your if-else, but with the condition you had, you were not going to enter to the part of the code to create the folder.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName, folderName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);
    
    // Get your Uploads folder
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    
    // Regex for splitting the file's extention like .pdf
    var patt1 = /\.[0-9a-z]+$/i;
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      // Create a folder with the name of the file you just uploaded in your root path
      // DriveApp.createFolder(fileName.split(patt1)[0]);
      // Create the file in your Uploads folder and a folder
      var file = folder.createFile(ss);
      folder.createFolder(fileName.split(patt1)[0]);
      return file.getName(); 
    } else return null;
    
  } catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

### EDIT

Notice the class folder has a special method called `createFolder(name)`, which will allow you to create a folder in the currently folder you are handling as I put it in my Updated code. Check the Updated Docs links for more info.

### Docs

I used these docs to help you find the solution to your problem:

- [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Class Folder - createFolder(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFolder(String))

Comment: Thank you, @Alberto, everything worked just fine!  1. Form successfully refreshes after each submission.  2. Folders are now successfully created and renamed after their file names on each upload.

Though the files are appearing in the primary UPLOADS folder, as desired, their corresponding (empty) folders created, are being directed to the default google drive. Are the files meant to split from their folders? 

Apart from this, everything else is now perfect.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I updated my answer to help you with your doubts in your last point.