# List all folders and subfolders in a google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone help me adapt the code taken from here

http://www.acrosswalls.org/ortext-datalinks/list-google-drive-folder-file-names-urls/

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'home folder';

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)

  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFolders();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('folders');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );

  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

to also list subfolders (it only lists folders within the first folder right now). I feel like it's very easy but can't quite figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an adapted version of the code you have provided with the requirements you need:

```
function listFolderContents(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('folders');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  // Get all folders
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var file;
  // Iterate over them
  while(folders.hasNext()){
    file = folders.next();
    sheet.appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl()]);
  }
}
```

You have to use `DriveApp.getFolders();` to get all folders in your Drive and then you can iterate over them.

### Docs

Please, check these docs to get more familiar on how to handle Drive folders using Apps Script:

- [Class DriveApp - getFolders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolders).
- [Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder).

Comment: Excellent - thanks! Out of interest, how would you only search specific folders, or even better, search multiple folders? I've got more folders than I realised so need to narrow the search. Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you. Please, consider to mark it as the correct answer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786435/upload-naming-folders-to-a-destination-folder-on-google-drive-using-google-app/58800826?noredirect=1#comment103903357_58800826) other post, it may help you with your current doubt